# Screenshot of the Gnome Shell Activities screen

Tags: gnome, screenshot

Is there a way to take a screenshot of the gnome shell activities screen i.e the screen that pops up on pressing the Win key or Alt+F1? The PrintScr button works normally but doesn't seem to work when I'm on the activities screen. Is this normal behavior? If yes, are there workarounds?

Comment: Can you try setting a delay of a few seconds in the screenshot tool?

Answer (score 2):

If other things are failing, use the import command --

`import -window root screenshot.jpg`

It will pick up things that often aren't found by using gnome-screenshot or shutter, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the gnome-screenshot (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gnome-screenshot --interactive`) tool and enable "*Grab the whole desktop*" and then enable *"Grab after a delay of 5 seconds"*

Then simply click "Take Screenshot" and bring up your Activities screen by pressing Win/Super key and in 5 seconds it will take a Screenshot.

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are really many ways of taking screenshots! [This blog post](http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-ubuntu-linux) details many of them.

My personal favourite is [`scrot`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot).